# Pci device not showing up

Tags: wireless-networking, drivers, pci-express, wifi-driver, supermicro

Sorry if the question has been answered before but my google skills are at an end.

I'm running Proxmox 6.3-6 on a Supermicro A1SAM-2550F Motherboard and want to connect an Atheros AR5BXB92 / AR9280 Mini-PCIe Card via an PCIe 1X Adapter and find it directly within Proxmox, not in a VM. But the card just doesn't show up anywhere.

lspci, lshw or dmesg doesn't show any sign of the card, not even an unknown or unrecognized card.

The Atheros card ist working on two other computers without a problem (Windows and FreeBSD) and the Adapter Card is working on the PCIe Slot on the Supermicro Motherboard when I connect a different wifi mini-pcie card (which unfortunately doesn't support AP-Mode).

As far as I could find out the driver ath9k or ath5k should be within the proxmox/debian kernel.
I can't install the atheros_firmware as it conflicts with the pve_firmware.

Am I missing something? It is as far as I know an offbrand card I got of ebay, but the chipset should be genuine.

I read in another post that on some cards it is possible to tape off one of the connectors to bypass some kind of block. Which would surprise me because the card is working in other systems.

It would be great if someone could just push me in the right direction as I'm completely lost...

Thanks in advance,
Robin.